# How to submit a very extensive url

Tags: c#, json, wcf, iis-10

I have a URL with a 27 kB JSON parameter.

```
http://192.168.0.174:80/Service1.svc/CargarClientes?json=VERY_LONG_JSON_PARAMETER
```

But when I execute the statement it indicates the following error:

> Request URL Too Long HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.

How can I solve this situation, since I must send the data in that way?

Comment: Use HTTP POST instead. And if that's not available, then you simply can't do it.

Comment: get requests cannot be this long.  Posts yes, gets no

Comment: You're going to have to break up the request into pieces or submit it in a different way (POST, instead of GET). There's no way to use a 27 kB URL (at least not reliably), and the server you're hitting won't take it, which is why you're getting that error.

Comment: Thanks Ed Cottrell, How can I send it in pieces?

Comment: Can you please provide further details on why you are required to send such a massive amount of information in the URL rather than simply doing a POST?

Comment: I need to upload data from a mobile to a server, I do not do it by POST because I need to get the new data consecutively.

Answer (score 1):

In theory it should be possible to use any length url, but in reality this not like that.

> If you keep URLs under 2000 characters, they'll work in virtually any
>   combination of client and server software.

See *[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/2572335)* answer for details: